# $(1,1)$ representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

How do you prove that the $(1,1)$ representation of the $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ group acts on symmetric, traceless tensors of rank 2?

Comment: I upvoted the question, as a useful/interesting one, even though it contains an error: the (1,1) representation pertains to the $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ group, not to $SO(1,3)$. This problem is solved by Mueller and Kirsten in their introductory textbook on supersymmetry.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Many books on quantum field theory use this fact without giving any justification for it. Therefore my first instinct was to ask this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon a better look, it was not solved explicitely in a textbook. Start first with the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition of a tensor product of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ in a formal manner as:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \otimes \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) =  \left[\left(0,0\right)\oplus \left(1,1\right)\right]_S \oplus \left[\left(1,0\right)\oplus \left(0,1\right)\right]_A $$

In the LHS you have $\psi_{a\dot{a}}\otimes \phi_{b\dot{b}} \equiv \chi_{a\dot{a}b\dot{b}}$, to which you can use the Infeld-van der Waerden symbol $\sigma^{\alpha}_{~a\dot{a}}$ and $ \left(\sigma_{\alpha\beta}\right) _{a} ^{~b}$ to go to Lorentz indices which could be manipulated in the RHS to the sum (in a vector space sense) of a trace of 2nd rank tensor, then the traceless symmetric part of that tensor and the fully antisymmetrical part of that tensor.  The full details with calculations in case of Maxwell and Einstein gravitational fields are found in chapters 5 and 6 of Moshe Carmeli and Shimon Malin's *Theory of Spinors: An Introduction*, WS, 2000.